# angular 5 convert image to base64

Tags: javascript, typescript, canvas, base64, angular5

I have a problem converting an image to base64, it converts well, but when I try to open with the base64 the image does not come out at all, I do not know what problem I have.

```
<img id="imageid" src="http://localhost:8000/media/db.png" alt="">

getBase64Image() {
    var data = document.getElementById("imageid");
    html2canvas(data).then(canvas => {  
        var imgconverted = canvas.toDataURL("data:image/jpeg;base64"); 
        console.log(imgconverted, 'base64');
    });  
}
```

this comes out as a result that supposedly is fine, but I open it in the browser and the image does not come out only a frame.

```
data:image/png;base64,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
```

I hope you can help me no matter what the problem is.

Comment: looks like the converted image is actually showing but its a white square..

Comment: if exact, it only comes out white but in reality the image is not white, when I use for example https://www.base64-image.de this page, it converts the image well to base64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently a bug for images in HTML2Canvas: [link to bug](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/1646)